# operating on cells column in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a table consisting of many rows.

```
<table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="2" border="1" bgcolor="white" id="hiddenScoreTable" style="width: 635px;"><thead><tr><td align="center" style="width: 35px;">hand</td><th colspan="3" style="width: 200px;">bero</th><th colspan="3" style="width: 200px;">habazlam</th><th colspan="3" style="width: 200px;">linkin</th></tr><tr></tr></thead><tbody style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;"><tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3000</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>3000</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>3000</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3000</td><td>5</td><td>105</td><td>3000</td><td>20</td><td>120</td><td>4000</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>4000</td><td>25</td><td>130</td><td>3000</td><td>11</td><td>131</td><td>5000</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>4000</td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td>3000</td><td>5</td><td>136</td><td>5000</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>70</td><td>170</td><td>4000</td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td>4000</td><td>5</td><td>141</td><td>5000</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>173</td><td>5000</td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td>4000</td><td>20</td><td>161</td><td>5000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

i want the 4th cell array, cell[3], to be compared element by element to delete all similar elements and just keep the first one ==> table becomes:

```
<table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="2" border="1" bgcolor="white" style="width: 635px;" id="hiddenScoreTable"><thead><tr><td align="center" style="width: 35px;">hand</td><th style="width: 200px;" colspan="3">bero</th><th style="width: 200px;" colspan="3">habazlam</th><th style="width: 200px;" colspan="3">linkin</th></tr><tr></tr></thead><tbody style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;"><tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3000</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>3000</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>3000</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>5</td><td>105</td><td></td><td>20</td><td>120</td><td style="color:red">4000</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td style="color:red">4000</td><td>25</td><td>130</td><td></td><td>11</td><td>131</td><td style="color:red">5000</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td></td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td></td><td>5</td><td>136</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>70</td><td>170</td><td></td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td style="color:red;">4000</td><td>5</td><td>141</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>173</td><td style="color:red">5000</td><td>0</td><td>130</td><td></td><td>20</td><td>161</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

and i wanna color all values > 3000.

I need a solution only **based on jquery selectors,if possible** ( i don't want to recursively save the value and compare).

PS: i already have a solution working, but i want to ask:
when u select the 4th td by jquery selector, can u compare a td to its previous using any kind of jquery selectors/functions??

if u use .index(), you are getting the index of that td in the parent, which is row. you can tweak it a bit to be selecting the td in the td array, no problem. but is there a selector that lets you compare CONSECUTIVE TDs ?????

Thanks

Comment: Show the mark-up of the table, please. It helps us make an example faster/more easily.

Comment: That does not make sense: *I need a solution javascript free* and *i feel that this is done by JQuery in no time*. Don't you know that jQuery is JavaScript? If you don't want to use JavaScript, you can't use jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to hide the text and apply the new `background-color`, or hide both text *and* not apply the new `background-color` (if the removed value was >3000)? Also jQuery works within JavaScript (as Felix points out), each cell will have to be examined, the result saved, *and* have the values compared...

Comment: @David i'm sorry but this is my first post , so i dont know how to show the markup u ask for.

@Felix I know that JQuery is a javascript library, but what i meant was i need to find the solution using only jquery selectors. i pointed out that i found a solution using javascript, but i dont need this. i wanna learn jquery better.

Comment: Use your web-browser, select 'view source', copy the relevant portion of the html (the table). Come back to this question, click on the 'edit' link (below the tags) and paste the code into the question (and format it appropriately, indenting each line by four spaces **or** with the code selected click on the ` {} ` button). Click on 'save.'

Comment: @David what i want is to hide all values that have shown before in that column. if a value > 3000 shows up, color the first one, and eliminate the others.

Comment: @user806953: please take a look at the latest edit to my answer. I *think* that achieves what you've asked for?

Comment: all you guys had great answers, and all working...
but please see the updated question. If I wasnt clear from the start, Im definitely sorry....

Answer (score 2):

The following works, albeit it might be a little computationally intensive, iterating over each `td` *and* running the `if` on each; but it's the only way I could think of, so I offer:

```
$('td').each(
    function(){
        var numberString = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        if (numberString == 'NaN') {
            return false;
        }
        else if (numberString > 3000) {
            $(this).addClass('classForValuesOverThreeThousand');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UDzTZ/).

---

**Edited** after realising I'd omitted part one of the question.

The following is, frankly, horrible; but it does work. And does allow for any number of rows and columns; if anyone has any better ideas I'd be more than happy for suggestions as to how to improve this (feel free to edit improvements in<sup>1</sup>, if it becomes CW at some point, that's fine; I'd rather learn how to improve the following than worry about the rep):

```
var n, vals = [];
$('tr').each(
    function(r){
        $(this).find('td').each(
            function(c){
                n = [parseInt($(this).text(), 10)];
                if (parseInt(n) == parseInt(vals[c])){
                    $(this).text('');
                }
                vals[c] = n;
                if (vals[c] > 3000) {
                    $(this).addClass('classForValuesOverThreeThousand');
                }
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UDzTZ/2/).

---

**Edited** to address latest comment (to the question) from the OP:

> what [I] want is to hide all values that have shown before in that column. [If] a value > 3000 shows up, color the first one, and eliminate the others.

```
var n, vals = [];
$('tr').each(
    function(r){
        $(this).find('td').each(
            function(c){
                n = [parseInt($(this).text(), 10)];
                if (parseInt(n) == parseInt(vals[c])){
                    $(this).text('');
                }
                vals[c] = n;
                if (vals[c] > 3000 && $(this).text().length) {
                    $(this).addClass('classForValuesOverThreeThousand');
                }
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UDzTZ/3/).

The above removes the duplicated value from the cell, and then tests that the value is > 3000 *and* that text is present.

---

1. If you're able to add an edit, please add that/those edit(s) *to* the posted answer, rather than over-writing them, so it gets incrementally better and each stage can be seen...

Comment: @David Thomas in the question he asked only about the forth column. Anyway you could easyly wrap my answer into a function to which you pass the col you want to process and get the desired result

Comment: @Nicola, and then he shows it being applied to the fourth and eighth columns. And none of the other columns have any consecutively repeating values.

Comment: @David Thomas good point,i didn't notice this, i'll update my script!

Comment: @David Thomas, i edited my answer considering all the columns. It only assumes that alle the rows have the same number of columns. I've run your code on my fiddle and it doesn't work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/10/ but maybe that's how i interpreted the question: only distinct values in columns

Comment: @Nicola: [yeah, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Aw7J6/11/); the problem was that my version relies on CSS class-names to work, which you didn't copy over to your test :)

Comment: No i mean another thing: how i read the question, for example, in column 2 you should only have one row (row 2) with value 3400, because i interpreted that you had only distinct value in columns. I think you interpreted in another way (not the same value in tw adiacent rows!) 
Right now i don't know who got it right! :)

Comment: @Nicola: ah, in which case yeah. I assumed that if *cell[n]* in *row 1* is 25, and *cell[n]* in *row 2* is also 25, then row 2 should not show that value. But the question, as written, seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var results = {};  
$('tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(index, element){
    var thisElement = $(element).html();
    if (results[thisElement]){
        $(element).html('');
    }else{
        results[thisElement] = true;
        if (thisElement > 3000){
            $(element).css('color','red');
        }
    } 

});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/1/ that works with the second column (i didn't want to write four columns of markup, but you just need to change the colindex in the nth-child selector)

EDIT - i edited the fiddle so that it's clearer http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/2/

EDIT -2 I edited my fiddle to achieve the same effects on all columns:

```
var numOfColumns = $('#transform tr:first > td').length;

for (i=1; i<=numOfColumns; i++){
    var results = {};
$('#transform tr td:nth-child('+i+')').each(function(index, element){

    var thisElement = $(element).html();

    if (results[thisElement]){
        $(element).html('&nbsp;');

    }else{
        results[thisElement] = true;
        if (thisElement > 3000){
            $(element).css('color','red');
        }
    }  

});
}
```

Fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/9/

Comment: In part one i just selected all the 'td' in the column with the nth child selector. I used an object (results) to cache values: if a value exist in the results object, i delete it from the html, otherwise i add it to the object so the other values equal to that get deleted afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Jquery IS javascript so you can't have a javascript free answer and still use Jquery.

If you don't need to keep track of the values and you have to do this after you write out the table then you'll have to go back through each element.  You don't need recursion just to remember what the last value was.
Try this:

```
    var lastVal = "";
    $("table tr td:nth-child(4)").each(function(){
        var myVal = $(this).text();
        if(myVal == lastVal) {
            $(this).text("");
        } else {
            lastVal = myVal;
        }
        if(lastVal > 3000) $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
```

Comment: This just takes into account the last val: you might have the same number in the first and in the last cell and you should take that into account.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Nicola.  Can you provide a table example like you did above for this use case?

Comment: Oh I see...so do you want this same behavior for any column in your table?  You are correct.  This is just addressing values in the 4th column.

Comment: here is a fiddle with your script: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/6/ as you can see it doesn't work, same values in column 2 are not taken out That is because you just compare each td with the previous value. What he nedds to achieve is to have in the column only DISTINCT values. check the difference with my script http://jsfiddle.net/Aw7J6/5/ here you have only distinct values

Comment: @Nicola I understand what you're saying but that isn't what the question is asking for "i want the 4th cell array, cell[3], to be compared element by element to delete all similar elements and just keep the first one"